# iCloud username and password autocomplete hints

Tags: javascript, html, macos, icloud

How can I tell iCloud which fields to correctly use for our register form? Here, it is using the name field when we want to it use the email field.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `autocomplete` and `name` attribute of the fields so the autocomplete engine in the browser knows what to do.

You may also need to contain the input elements within a form.

[For more information go to this link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/input/form/label-and-name-inputs?hl=en)

Here's a quick table:

[image: Table of autocomplete]

Comment: Maybe you could also add that the fields have to be surrounded by a form.